# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 When using Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, frameworks

I am developing an iOS framework that incorporates the Parse framework. When I build the framework I get the following errors:

[image]

I tried adding all of the libraries that were recommended in other Stack Overflow questions such as the Social.framework and Accounts.framework as well as the FBSDKCoreKit.framework.

Any suggestions?

Also, what is the best method to link my framework (called CDPSync.framework) against the Parse.framework if I also want to incorporate the Parse.framework into apps that incorporate the CDPSync.framework? In other words I want to use Parse in both my custom framework and apps that incorporate my custom framework.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my approach:

1. Click your project settings (includes General, Capabilities, Info, etc.).
2. Click on Build Phases.
3. Open the "Link Binary with Libraries" list.
4. At the bottom, click the plus symbol to add the missing framework/files.